# Is apparmor active after installation?

Tags: installation, apparmor

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I tell that apparmor is working?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/236377/how-can-i-tell-that-apparmor-is-working)

I want to know is apparmor active after installing ubuntu12.04 ?

Thank you

Comment: you can know status of it http://askubuntu.com/questions/236377/how-can-i-tell-that-apparmor-is-working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Possibly Mohammad is not asking about querying the current state but asking what the default status is on a vanilla installation. If the question was meant as: Is Apparmor activated by default on install, the aswer is Yes.

Answer (score 0):

AppArmor is enabled by default.